# How do I gain access to south Crestwood?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Can someone please help me make this game a bit less infuriating and time-wasting than it is, by explaining how I can gain access to the southern part of Crestwood? I'm trying to do "Here Lies the Abyss", and cannot go remotely close enough for the walkthrough videos to be useful—they assume that I already arrived at Hawke's spot.

Here is a screenshot of the zone's map for me with the fog-of-war I couldn't access:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

South Crestwood becomes accessible after you get a certain way into the main quest for that area. You should have received a quest as part of this to recapture the old fort, which you'll find if you follow the road south out of Crestwood.

> Once you've taken the fort, you can access the controls for the dam and drain the lake, which gives you access to the next plot area. It also gives you access to the route into South Crestwood.

Answer (score 1):

There is a path in the southern part of the town in Crestwood (the place with the Mayor and the houses).

If you follow that path south you can reach the cave where the Grey Warden friend of Hawke resides.

All this can be done WITHOUT draining the lake.

Source: I did it myself.

Answer (score -1):

I got some help on another site from a user called HarukoBass; he at least confirmed that the southern part of Crestwood is not blocked, and that made me look some more, and I eventually found the path.

The path marked with red in the following screenshot was the part that was not clear to me, and I couldn't find it until someone confirmed that at least *some* path is accessible:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/W1R5e75.png]

Comment: Please limit questions and answers to tangible facts, not lengthy rants about how you feel the game designers have let you down by not making things obvious and linear.

Comment: BTW, this is not the first time I read the "obvious, linear" argument; it's classic, fanatic fanboyism. I knew someone will come up with it. That's why I wrote what I wrote.

Comment: 1) Trimming an answer to the actual facts of gameplay in order to keep the signal-to-noise level to this site's high standards is not censorship. 2) anyone who looks can see that it was edited and if they want they're one click away from seeing your full 'answer'.  3) I'm not the one who made the edit, just the one who  approved it. 4) Rants about "classic fanatic fanboyism" are *also* off topic on this site. Save it for your personal blog.

Comment: I'm not the first DA3 player who feels forced to spend hours (literally, not exaggeration) running around in the virtual world looking for a gate, door, or exit; I have read on forums about other players who had the same experience. If you want to help developers keep thinking that their product is perfect, and they should keep avoiding to make a game "obvious and linear", by making it "confusing and circular" (perfect opposite?), be my guest (you're the boss here anyway). Just please don't pretend that censorship is "minimizing signal-to-noise" and this site is void of emotion. Thanks.